# How refresh wp_schedule_event without restart a plugin

Tags: cron

I create option page for set optional recurrence (daily or hourly wp_schedule_event, when I change for example, from daily to hourly through option page in back-end, how can I fire wp_schedule_event again to start cron jon hourly?